# Do something If post has a term from a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements, custom-taxonomy

I've got a custom taxonomy "library" that has 2 terms in it: "fiction" and "novels"

I am trying to do a function depending on what term from this taxonomy my post has.

So if the post is assigned to "fiction", I need to `//do something`, and if the post is assigned to "novels" that I need to `//do something else`

At very first, I've been trying with `is_tax`, but that doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
if ( is_tax('library','fiction' ) ) {   
    //do something
  } elseif ( is_tax('library','novels' ) ) {    
    //do something else
  }
```

I have also tried `has_term` but that doesn't work for me either.

```
if ( has_term ('fiction','library' ) ) {    
        //do something
      } elseif ( has_term ('novels','libary' ) ) {  
        //do something else
      }
```

So I want to give it a go with `wp_get_post_terms`, but I'm not sure exactly how to execute this one.

I'm trying this:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'library' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->name == 'fiction') {
            // do something
        }
        elseif($term->name == 'novels') {
            // do something else
        }
}
```

Am I missing something there? Specially this last one?

Answer (score 0):

**Get your category name by usign get_categories(); function**

```
$category_args = array(
    'type'                     => 'yourposttypename',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => 0,
    'orderby'                  => 'id',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'library',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

); 
$categories = get_categories( $category_args );
if(count($categories)>0)
{

        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
           if($category->name=='fiction')
           {
                // do something
           }
           else  if($category->name=='novels')
           {
                // do something else
           }
        }

}
```